# How to Validate geojson file in laravel?

Tags: laravel, file, upload, geojson

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255|unique:layers',
        'workspace' => 'required|max:1',
        'type' => 'required',
        'layer-file' => 'required|file|mimes:zip,kml|mimetypes:application/geo+json',
        'about' => 'sometimes|max:1000',
        'type' => 'required',
        'published' => 'required',
    ]);
```

I am Trying to upload geojson file into laravel. But in the validation it is not working.

Comment: What do you mean by `it is not working`?

Comment: mimetypes:application/geo+json'